# Char equals to String

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to check if a value from database table is equal to Char, in the view I tried

```
the following:
   <% if (Model.MethodOfPayment.ToString().Equals("W") == true)
                       {
                    %>
                    Wire  
                    <%} %>
                    <%else
                       { %>
                    <% if (Model.MethodOfPayment.ToString().Equals("C") == true)
                       {
                    %>
                    Cheque
                    <%} %>
                    <%} %>
```

Did not work!
In the controller to send the output to PDF Form: I tried the following:

```
string MyString = order.MethodOfPayment.ToString();
if (MyString == "W")
{
    pdfFormFields.SetField("MethodOfPayment", "W");
}
else
{
    if (MyString == "W")
    {
        pdfFormFields.SetField("MethodOfPayment", "C");
    }
}
```

Did not work either.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is MethodOfPayment an enum? You could do `Model.MethodOfPayment == MethodOfPayment.W` in your controller and use `SetField()` so you don't have to use an if statement in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
if (Model.MethodOfPayment == 'W')
```

If this doesn't work it simply means that the `MethodOfPayment` property doesn't equal to the `W` character. Try debugging your code to see exactly to which value it equals.